# how to filter data by foreign key value in template

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have two model called organization and staff.Staff model have onetoone relation with user and Foreignkey relation to the organization.The problem what i got is to filter the staffs by their related organization.I have tried liked this but didn't worked out.

models.py

```
class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True,
                                     related_name='organization')

.....other fields.....
```

views.py

```
def view_staff_users(request):
    staff_users = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
    organizations = Organization.objects.all()
    staffs_by_org = Staff.objects.select_related('organization')
     # tried this also:
    # staffs_by_org = []
    # print('staffff',staffs_by_org)
    # for organization in organizations:
    #     staffs = Staff.objects.filter(organization=organization)
    #     staffs_by_org.extend(staffs)
    #     print('staaa',staffs_by_org)
```

Edited views:

```
def view_staff_users(request):
staff_users = User.objects.filter(is_staff=True)
organizations = Organization.objects.all()
staffs_by_org = []
for organization in organizations:
        staffs_by_org = Staff.objects.filter(organization__name=organization).select_related('organization')
```

template

```
 {% for user in staffs_by_org %}
   # tried this also: {% for u in user.organization_set.all %}
   {{user.user.name}}
   {{user.username}}
   {{user.email}}
   {{user.user.organization}}

 {% endfor %}
```

Edit: My template looks like this.

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs customtab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#all" role="tab"><span class="hidden-sm-up"></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">All Staffs</span></a> </li>
{% for organization in organizations %}
     <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#{{organization.name}}" role="tab"><span class="hidden-sm-up"></span> <span class="hidden-xs-down">{{organization.name}}</span></a> </li>
{% endfor %}

    </ul>
          <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="all" role="tabpanel">
             {% for user in staff_users %}

               {{user.user.name}}
               {{user.username}}
               {{user.email}}
               {{user.user.organization}}

             {% endfor %}
             </div>
        {% for organization in organizations %}
        <div class="tab-pane tab" id="{{organization.name}}" role="tabpanel">
         {% endfor %}
         {% for user in staffs_by_org %}
               # tried this also: {% for u in user.organization_set.all %}
               {{user.user.name}}
               {{user.username}}
               {{user.email}}
               {{user.user.organization}}

             {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter for example with:

```
staffs_by_org = Staff.objects.filter(
    organization__name='My organization'
).select_related('organization')
```

The `staffs_by_org` is a `QuerySet` of `Staff`s. I therefore stronly advice to use `staff` in the iterator. You can access the organization with `staff.organization`:

```
{% for staff in staffs_by_org %}
   {{ staff.name }}
   {{ staff.user.username }}
   {{ staff.user.email }}
   {{ staff.organization }}
{% endfor %}
```

If the organization has for example a `name`, you can render it with:

```
{% for staff in staffs_by_org %}
   {{ staff.name }}
   {{ staff.user.username }}
   {{ staff.user.email }}
   {{ staff.organization.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that the `related_name` of a `ForeignKey` is the name of the relation in *reverse*. A better name is probably `'staff'`. If you refer to the user model, it is better to use [**`get_user_model()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model), since if you later change your mind, you can easily use another user model.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='staff'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(
        Organization,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        related_name='staff'
    )
```

Comment: the result is same.I am getting all the users but i want to filter it by organization name

Comment: thanks for the info i will use get_user_model instead

Comment: @Alice: ah, then you should filter, for example with `organization__name='my org name'`.

Comment: i want to show you the full template that i am trying.Can you please look through that?

Comment: i have edited my question .can you please look through that

Comment: How can i provide  organization_name dynamic here ? `organization__name='My organization'`

Answer (score 0):

I think one problem is that you created a loop that is rewriting itself instead of appending each batch of staff users to your queryset.

One way to do what you want (return all staff that belong to a set of organizations) is to use the `in` filter operator.

So, in your `views.py`:

```py
organizations = Organization.objects.all()
staffs_by_org = Staff.objects.filter(
    organization__in=organizations).select_related('organization')
```

This will return all staff from whatever `organizations` is.
If you want a dynamic filter for the organization name, then what you have to do is:

1. Pass the organization name to the request. This is usually done via
   URL parameters or query strings.
2. Change the `organizations` variable
       from `objects.all()` to `objects.filter(URL_PARAMETER)`

Then `staffs_by_org` will only return the staff from that organization.

Comment: this also returned the whole  staffs list(not filtering).Is passing the organization name/pk in the url parameter  the only method to filter staffs by organization dynamically?

Comment: Yes, it will return all organizations because of `organizations = Organization.objects.all()`. 

As Django is a server-based framework, the most common way to filter individual organizations is to pass it to the request.

Another way is for you to return all results and then filter them on the client side (using javascript, like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp), for example). How to filter it on the client-side however would have little to do with Django itself though.

Comment: This tutorial might help you how to implement this dynamic filter: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html